# Operating system and register parameters

Tags: memory, operating-system, stack, cpu, cpu-registers

For an operating system that has a CPU with 4 general purpose registers. What amount of parameters can pass to a system call by only using the CPU registers (i.e. not with the use of a block of memory or the stack)?

Just assume that the size of the registers is the same as the parameters that will be passed to the system call.

Comment: How will you pass parameter to system call? Are there any additional required arguments of system call besides parameters (are they going to general purpose reg or you machine has some special registers to do syscalls)? Is size of parameter equal to register width or not? (Did you attend you classes and read your textbook?)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is entirely hardware specific. Is the Program Counter a "general register?" In most processors it is but in other is isn't.

Is your Stack Pointer a "general register?" Again, in most processors it is but in other it isn't.

Your answer is likely then to range from 2 to 4, depending upon the hardware configuration.

Comment: I encountered this question in one of my tutorial questions and found the wording confusing and a bit vague. So I was hoping someone on here might understand it better than I, and potentially give me a good answer.

Comment: The gist of the question is "How many registers are free." You have to know how many registers you are starting with and how many registers are in use. Some systems include a frame pointer. In that case your answer might only be 1.